# How to install php svn extesion using brew?

Tags: php, svn, osx-mavericks, homebrew

I want to install [php svn extension](http://php.net/manual/en/svn.installation.php) using brew . I do not see any formula for my current php version (php56).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [this link](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php) to add php-svn pecl extension for php e.g

```
vim  /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-php/Formula/php56-svn.rb
```

edit

```
require File.expand_path("../../Abstract/abstract-php-extension", __FILE__)

class Php56Svn < AbstractPhp56Extension
  init
  homepage 'http://pecl.php.net/package/svn'
  url 'http://pecl.php.net/get/svn-1.0.2.tgz'
  head 'http://pecl.php.net/package/svn'

  depends_on 'subversion'

  def install
    Dir.chdir "svn-#{version}" unless build.head?

    ENV.universal_binary if build.universal?

    safe_phpize
    system "./configure", "--prefix=#{prefix}", phpconfig
    system "make"
    prefix.install "modules/svn.so"
    write_config_file if build.with? "config-file"
  end
end
```

`brew tap --repair`

`brew audit php56-svn`

`brew install php56-svn`